# Duplicate element Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my map and area. I'm doing a panorama with the area and map tags. I have a Javascript boxDisplay function which displays a box when I click on the area in question. But obviously, i don't know why but the elements duplicate. "screenshot"
.

The desired result is to be able to click on the areas without duplicates

[Image of duplicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mia8X.png)

Here's the code :

```js
function boxDisplay(title,link,PrdImage){
 document.getElementById("box").style.display = "block";
 document.getElementById("PrdImage").src = PrdImage;
 document.getElementById("PrdTitle").innerHTML = title;
 document.getElementById("LinkPrd").href = link;
}

function closeInfos(){
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
}


(function($) {
 $.fn.panorama360 = function(options){
  this.each(function(){
   var settings = {
    start_position: 0,
    image_width: 0,
    image_height: 0,
    mouse_wheel_multiplier: 20,
    bind_resize: true
   };
   if(options) $.extend(settings, options);
   var viewport = $(this);
   var panoramaContainer = viewport.children('.panorama-container');
   var viewportImage = panoramaContainer.children('img:first');
   if(settings.image_width<=0 && settings.image_height<=0){
    settings.image_width = parseInt(viewportImage.data("width"));
    settings.image_height = parseInt(viewportImage.data("height"));
    if (!(settings.image_width) || !(settings.image_height)) return;
   }
   var image_ratio = settings.image_height/settings.image_width;
   var elem_height = parseInt(viewport.height());
   var elem_width = parseInt(elem_height/image_ratio);
   var image_map = viewportImage.attr('usemap');
   var image_areas;
   var isDragged = false;
   var mouseXprev = 0;
   var scrollDelta = 0;

   viewportImage.height(elem_height).removeAttr("usemap").css("left",0).clone().css("left",elem_width+"px").insertAfter(viewportImage);

   panoramaContainer.css({
    'margin-left': '-'+settings.start_position+'px',
    'width': (elem_width*2)+'px',
    'height': (elem_height)+'px'
   });

   setInterval( function() {
    if (isDragged) return false;
    scrollDelta = scrollDelta * 0.98;
    if (Math.abs(scrollDelta)<=2) scrollDelta = 0;
    scrollView(panoramaContainer, elem_width, scrollDelta);
   }, 1);
   viewport.mousedown(function(e){
    if (isDragged) return false;
    $(this).addClass("grab");
    isDragged = true;
    mouseXprev = e.clientX;
    scrollOffset = 0;
    return false;
   }).mouseup(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("grab");
    isDragged = false;
    scrollDelta = scrollDelta * 0.45;
    return false;
   }).mousemove(function(e){
    if (!isDragged) return false;
    scrollDelta = parseInt((e.clientX - mouseXprev));
    mouseXprev = e.clientX;
    scrollView(panoramaContainer, elem_width, scrollDelta);
    return false;
   }).bind("mousewheel",function(e,distance){
    var delta=Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(distance)));
    delta=distance<0 ? -delta : delta;
    scrollDelta = scrollDelta + delta * 5;
    scrollView(panoramaContainer,elem_width,delta*settings.mouse_wheel_multiplier);
    return false;
   }).bind('contextmenu',stopEvent).bind('touchstart', function(e){
    if (isDragged) return false;
    isDragged = true;
    mouseXprev = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    scrollOffset = 0;
   }).bind('touchmove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isDragged) return false;
    var touch_x = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    scrollDelta = parseInt((touch_x - mouseXprev));
    mouseXprev = touch_x;
    scrollView(panoramaContainer, elem_width, scrollDelta);
   }).bind('touchend', function(e){
    isDragged = false;
    scrollDelta = scrollDelta * 0.45;
   });


   if (image_map) {

    $('map[name='+image_map+']').children('').each(function(){
                    var  area_coord, area_fragment;
     switch ($(this).attr("shape").toLowerCase()){
      case 'rect':
       area_coord = $(this).attr("coords").split(",");
                            area_fragment = $(".area");
       // opacity support in older browser
                            area_fragment.css({opacity:0.2});
       panoramaContainer.append(area_fragment.clone().data("stitch",1).data("coords",area_coord));
       break;
     }
    }).remove();
    image_areas = panoramaContainer.children(".area");
    repositionHotspots(image_areas,settings.image_height,elem_height,elem_width);
   }



  });
  
  function stopEvent(e){


  }

  function scrollView(panoramaContainer,elem_width,delta){
   var newMarginLeft = parseInt(panoramaContainer.css('marginLeft'))+delta;
   if (newMarginLeft > 0) newMarginLeft = -elem_width;
   if (newMarginLeft < -elem_width) newMarginLeft = 0;
   panoramaContainer.css('marginLeft', newMarginLeft+'px');
  }

  function repositionHotspots(areas,image_height,elem_height,elem_width){
   var percent = elem_height/image_height;
   areas.each(function(){
    area_coord = $(this).data("coords");
    stitch = $(this).data("stitch");
    switch (stitch){
     case 1:
      $(this).css({
       'left':  (area_coord[0]*percent)+"px",
       'top':  (area_coord[1]*percent)+"px",
       'width': ((area_coord[2]-area_coord[0])*percent)+"px",
       'height': ((area_coord[3]-area_coord[1])*percent)+"px"
      });
      break;
     case 2:
      $(this).css({
       'left':  (elem_width+parseInt(area_coord[0])*percent)+"px",
       'top':  (area_coord[1]*percent)+"px",
       'width': ((area_coord[2]-area_coord[0])*percent)+"px",
       'height': ((area_coord[3]-area_coord[1])*percent)+"px"
      });
      break;
    }
   });
  }
 }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Panorama 360&deg;</title>
 <meta name="description" content="Creative design agency that tries to make the complex feel simple." />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" media="all" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/panorama360.css" media="all" />
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.panorama360.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){
   $('.panorama-view').panorama360();
  });
 </script>
 <style>
    #box {
    border: 5px solid rebeccapurple;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 35px 15px 5px 15px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 190px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  
  #ClosePrdInfos {
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      top: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  #PrdImage{
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .BlocPrd{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="panorama">
  <div class="panorama-view">
   <div class="panorama-container">
    <img src="images/View_from_Sky_Tower_Akl_small.jpg" usemap="hotspots" data-width="4996" data-height="1300" alt="Panorama" />
    <map id="hotspots" name="hotspots"> 
     <area coords="3193,961,3392,1274" class="area" shape="rect" onClick="boxDisplay('Panneau 1','http://google.fr','images/triporteur.jpg')" >
     <area coords="2363,903,2531,1124" class="area"  shape="rect"  onClick="boxDisplay('Panneau ','http://google.fr','images/triporteur.jpg')">
     <area coords="1295,701,1388,930" class="area"  shape="rect"  onClick="boxDisplay('Panneau 2','http://google.fr','images/triporteur.jpg')">
    </map>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
   <img src="images/Close.png" height="16xp" width="16px" id="ClosePrdInfos" onClick="closeInfos()">
   <img src="#" id="PrdImage">
   <div class="BlocPrd">
     <div id="PrdTitle">Titre ICI</div>
     <p><a href="#" id="LinkPrd">Voir la fiche produit</a></p>
   </div>
 
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're missing the key/value pair here: `this.each(function(){`

Comment: Ok thank you i will take a look. Did you know how can i do ? Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duplicated your code, and the clone is created in the javascript, line 42:

```js
viewportImage.height(elem_height).removeAttr("usemap").css("left",0).clone().css("left",elem_width+"px").insertAfter(viewportImage);
```

If you want to get rid of it, you can simply take off what's after the `clone()`:

```js
viewportImage.height(elem_height).removeAttr("usemap").css("left",0)
```

But beware, **cloning is the normal behavior here**: since you want an image at 360 degrees, the image clone is here so that you can seamlessly go from the right of the image to the left

Here's a demo:
https://codepen.io/z0rzi/pen/ZEGwoRW

Comment: Yes i know, the cloning is not the problem here. The problem is that the areas duplicate i don't know why